# How to set transition duration programmatically in MotionLayout?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I set a new transition manually in code like this:

```
intro_motion_layout.setTransition(R.id.middle, R.id.end)
```

Is there a way I can also set the duration this way?

I have multiple `ConstraintSets` defined in XML and I switch between them when the first transition is complete using `onTransitionCompleted`. I have one `Transition` in my XML and it uses duration correctly there but the following `Transitions` that I set in code happen very quickly and I cant find a way to change their durations.

Answer (score 7):

```
intro_motion_layout.setTransition(R.id.middle, R.id.end)
intro_motion_layout.setTransitionDuration(1000)
intro_motion_layout.transitionToEnd()
```

worked for me

Answer (score -1):

if you define your Transition on your xml, then you set your start/end id, it will take the information from xml

```
<Transition
    app:constraintSetStart="@id/bottom_sheet_closed"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/bottom_sheet_open"
    app:duration="1550"
    app:interpolator="easeIn">

    <OnSwipe
        app:dragDirection="dragUp"
        app:moveWhenScrollAtTop="true"
        app:touchAnchorId="@id/divider"
        app:touchAnchorSide="top" />

</Transition>
```

then programmatically you can do:

```
root.motion_layout.setTransition(R.id.bottom_sheet_closed, R.id.bottom_sheet_open)
root.motion_layout.transitionToEnd()
```

and everythink will work